# What does "alma sucia" mean?

Tags: modismos, definiciones

What does it mean? I've checked the literal meaning with Google:

> dirty soul

I was looking for something more elegant, that shows its tone. Is it an idiom?

Comment: Where did you hear it? Was it in a book, TV, song...? You could put the full sentence if you remember it. Usually it is useful to know the context if it is not an idiom.

Comment: I saw it tattooed on someone's arm, hard to tell, thanks for responding Joul

Answer (score 4):

Never heard it before either, however depending on the context or the meaning you want I'd translate it as one of `corrupt|corrupted|black|dark|nasty|impure|horrible|wicked|vile|lewd+soul`

Answer (score 2):

It literally means "Dirty Soul". It's not a common phrase in Spanish, more like an attempt to coin a badass sounding term (i.e. "Thug Life", "Bad Boy", "Hell Raiser", etc). Never heard that phrase used in common life.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard it before.  Maybe a regional/slang term for something else?  As far as I know, you're correct, "dirty soul" is the actual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "cruel heart" or "evil" basically.

Comment: No necesariamente. Un chorro puede portarse mal y como consecuencia ser sometido a tortura en la cárcel. Quién sería el *cruel heart* y quién el *alma sucia* en ese caso?